# How do cosmologists measure cosmological distances and the expansion history of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, bao

Cosmologists from the BOSS and eBoss surveys construct 3-D maps of correlated galaxy positions, measure their redshifts and use the comoving BAO feature as a standard ruler. With these data, how do they proceed to evaluate cosmic distances and infer the expansion history of the universe?

Comment: There is a good explanation here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_acoustic_oscillations

Comment: Are you still intereseted for an answer ?